# Unable to switch to parent window saying window is closed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing on IE. After clicking I switch to child window but unable to return to parent window giving error "Window is closed".

```
String parent= driver.getWindowHandle(); //after clicking new window pop up
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[@href='javascript:submitExport()'])[5]"))).click();
System.out.println("parent"+parent);

for (String child : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
   System.out.println("child"+child);
   if(!parent.equalsIgnoreCase(child))
   {
    driver.switchTo().window(child);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Export')]")));

    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Export')]"));

    ele.click();
   }

}
System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle());
driver.close();
System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle());
driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace (exception) as well

Comment: Basically, when you are using switchTo() it's basically used mostly for frames inside a window. However, when you are going into a new frame you need to go back to the default one. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750227/moving-back-to-parent-frame-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

just look your code carefully,

```
System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle());
driver.close();
System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle());
driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

it seems like you are calling switchTo().window(parent) after closing the driver.
driver.close() This method closes the the browser window on which the focus is set.
This might be issue that you are trying to close child browser, but it leads falsely to close parent or because of some action they gets closed automatically may possible.
use only when there are multiple browser windows gets opened.
dont close driver before calling switchTo().

i hope this might work for you,

```
System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle()); 
driver.switchTo().window(parent);   
System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle());    
driver.close();
```

basic way,

you can use a set for storage keep record and iterator to iterate through it,

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[@href='javascript:submitExport()'])[5]"))).click()
Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles(); // take all window info
Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
String parent = it.next(); // store
String child = it.next(); // store
driver.switchTo().window(child); // switching
driver.close(); // close child window
driver.switchTo().window(parent); // switching
driver.quit(); // close
```

Answer (score -1):

You may refer this logic,

```
//It will open new tab using Javascript
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");

//Manage to switch driver on newly opened tab
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size() - 1));

//Manage to switch driver on existing old tab
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size() - 2));
```

Comment: Downvoting because the answer assumes the windows returned by `getWindowHandles()` are sorted by the order in which the windows were opened. This is explicitly not the case, as the window handles returned are documented to be returned in no specific order.

Comment: @JimEvans No problem on down vote, Please correct the things what should be. As far we know and we use this one only !